# MySQL: Possible variable lifetime issue, possible scope issue, honestly not sure

Tags: mysql, sql

So, recently inherited a project so old nobody who was involved in it works at this company anymore, in this project is a database, and in this database I have some tables:

```
TableA: userID | attrA | attrB | ... | role | flag | TableB: parent | child |
             1 |     A |     B | ... |    1 |    1 |              1 |     2 |
          etc.                                                    1 |     3 |
                                                                  2 |     5 |
                                                                  5 |    17 |
```

(Never seen this in a relational database before, but alas)
So, wrote a query very much like this one (MySQL 5.7):

```
SELECT
    @parents := user.userID as ID,
    user.attrA as A,
    user.attrB as B,
    IFNULL(
        (SELECT @parents AS inner
        FROM (SELECT parent, child FROM TableB ORDER BY child, parent) roles
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET(parent, @parents)
        AND @parents := IF(FIND_IN_SET(child, @parents), @parents, CONCAT(@parents, ',', child))
        ORDER BY inner DESC LIMIT 1),
        @parents
    ) AS roles
FROM TableA WHERE userID = ? AND flag = 1
```

This results in something like

```
ID | A | B | roles
 1 | A | B | 1,2,3,5,17
```

Which is being called by a server. Now, here's the series of events that unfolded: Write query, test it, works perfectly and consistently, add nothing else, shut down computer, next day, boot computer, start server, query no longer functions on the server. The inner query will... Well, I don't know what it's doing. It always gives me roles == ID, but removing the IFNULL function doesn't change that fact, I thought it might be because ID was an int, converting to char also doesn't change anything. Also, running the query manually, through command line and through an interface, still works perfectly every time. I tinkered further, and it turns out if I run the query twice before using it on the serverside, the second time, it works.

So, given I have made exactly zero changes to the codebase between it working and it not, I have no idea where to even begin trying to figure this out. I'd assume I have some scope or lifetime issue that's causing the `@parents` variable to get overwritten or nulled or something, but... I mean, again, it works everywhere else I've tried to use it. Hoping the issue is glaringly obvious and it'll be easy for someone else to point it out.

Cheers.

Comment: What have you never seen before? That's a very common way to represent hierarchical data in an RDBMS.

Comment: Oh, I've just never seen hierarchical data in a relational database before. Didn't mean to imply there's anything wrong with it.

Comment: `@` variables persist between queries on the same connection. If you don't initialize `@parents` before the query, you'll be concatenating to the value left from the previous query.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20181221162916/http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: You might find the solution to what you're trying to do on that page as well.

Comment: The server opens a fresh connection to the DB on each request... Or, at least, it should be... I'll look into it. Thing is, I'd assume the variable should be overwritten in that first SELECT step, and I've been using the same connection in my interface to test it, and haven't run into any stale vars.

Comment: What is the `@parent` variable for, you nefer use it.

Comment: Maybe that's supposed to be `@parents`?

Comment: Ah, yes, typo, my bad.

Comment: There are caveats about depending on the order of assignments within a `SELECT` list.

Comment: I thought so... I moved the assignment to the WHERE clause as I was under the impression it executes before SELECT, and the result was the same.